# Regex for string like 7h AM/ 17h PM

Tags: angular, validation

I want to validator string like input form like    7h AM/ 17h PM ,I try to many pattern but not corect

Comment: Is this string input is based on 12h/24h format? because 17h PM is not valid time. It should be either 5h PM (12h clock) or 17h (24hr clock).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the string input is based on 12h format.

```js
let regex = /^(([0]*[1-9]{1}|[1]+[0]|[1]*[1-2]{1})[h]\s(AM|PM))$/;

function testPattern(value) {
  console.log(value + ' ==> ' + regex.test(value));
}

testPattern('7h AM');
testPattern('07h AM');
testPattern('17h AM');
testPattern('25h AM');
testPattern('12h AM');
testPattern('12h PM');
```

I hope this solution works for you.